# Hacer que progressbar cambie de color gradualmente

Tags: wpf, progressbar

trato de hacer que mi progressbar cambie de color "de rojo a amarillo y de amarillo a verde (dependiendo de su valor) pero gradualmente. Este es el codigo que tengo:

```
 private void pb2_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {

        if (pb2.Value>0 && pb2.Value<33)
        {
            pb2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }


        else if (pb2.Value > 33 && pb2.Value < 75)
        {
            pb2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
        }



        else if (pb2.Value > 75 && pb2.Value < 100)
        {
            pb2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }
    }
```

Pero esto hace que los colores cambien bruscamente, y yo quiero que cambien gradualmente.

Con gradualmente me refiero a que por ejemplo: si esta en rojo, no cambie repentinamente a amarillo.

Comment: para eso no tendrias que ir cambando a colores intermedios?

Comment: Ya lo intente asi, pero el cambio de color se sigue notando muy brusco, y aparte necesitaria agregar muchisimos colores.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de responder, agradezco la pregunta de manera personal porque fue un desafío y me entretuve resolviéndolo.

**Aclaración inicial:**

Esta solución consta de 2 partes, la ProgressBar y una clase Converter de tipo `IMultiValueConverter`.
Voy a suponer que sabes usar Converters así que me voy a saltar esa parte.

**Nota:**

Porqué `MultiValueConverter` y no Converter común? Porque así le puedes pasar 2 parámetros, que serían: el `Value` y el `Maximum`, ya que la ProgressBar puede tener un `Maximum` diferente a 100, lo que daría un error en el `Converter`.

**El Converter:**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace DemoQueMeHizoHervirLaCabeza
{
    public class ProgressValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Convierte un color en otro
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="oldColor">Color original</param>
        /// <param name="newColor">Color deseado</param>
        /// <param name="valor">Valor de la ProgressBar</param>
        /// <param name="min">Valor mínimo del rango</param>
        /// <param name="max">Valor máximo del rango</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Color MixByValue(Color oldColor, Color newColor, double valor, double min, double max, double limit)
        {
            double rango = max == limit ? max - min : (max + 1) - min;
            double factor = 100 / rango;
            double oldAlpha = 100 - System.Convert.ToInt32((valor - min) * factor);
            double newAlpha = 100 - oldAlpha;

            oldAlpha = oldAlpha / 100;
            newAlpha = newAlpha / 100;

            byte r = (byte)((oldColor.R * oldAlpha) + newColor.R * newAlpha);
            byte g = (byte)((oldColor.G * oldAlpha) + newColor.G * newAlpha);
            byte b = (byte)((oldColor.B * oldAlpha) + newColor.B * newAlpha);
            return Color.FromRgb(r, g, b);
        }

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double value = (double)values[0];
            double limit = (double)values[1];

            if (value > 0 && value < 33)
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(MixByValue(Colors.Red, Colors.Orange, value, 0, 32, limit));
            }
            else if (value >= 33 && value < 75)
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(MixByValue(Colors.Orange, Colors.Yellow, value, 33, 74, limit));
            }
            else if (value >= 75 && value <= 100)
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(MixByValue(Colors.Yellow, Colors.Green, value, 75, 100, limit));
            }

            return Brushes.Black;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**La ProgressBar:**

El **Foreground** de esta debe apuntar al Converter, pasándole, como parámetros de conversión, el `Value` y el `Maximum`:

```
<ProgressBar Value="{Binding ElementName=valueslider, Path=Value}">
    <ProgressBar.Foreground>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ProgressValueConverter}" >
            <Binding Path="Value" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
            <Binding Path="Maximum" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </ProgressBar.Foreground>
</ProgressBar>
```

**Nota:**

Recuerda cambiar el **namespace** del Converter y el `Value` de la ProgressBar ya que para el ejemplo lo tenía Bindeado a un Slider para poder ir probando.

**Explicación:**

En palabras simples, el Converter obtiene el valor y lo transforma en un número porcentual que oscila entre los valores que asignas como mínimo y máximo por cada color, y tomando en cuenta esos 3 valores numéricos, combina 2 colores en distintas "proporciones", es como decirle al método, mezcla 2 partes de rojo con 1 de azul.

Podrías dividir el método Convert en más partes para agregar más colores y el método funcionaría igual, tu solo metes los valores, los colores que quieres y el método los irá mezclando automáticamente, acá un ejemplo del método Convert dividido para que cambie de color cada 10 puntos:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    double value = (double)values[0];
    double limit = (double)values[1];

    if (value > 0 && value <= 9)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(MixByValue(Colors.White, Colors.Yellow, value, 0, 9, limit));
    }
    else if (value >= 10 && value < 20)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(MixByValue(Colors.Yellow, Colors.YellowGreen, value, 10, 19, limit));
    }
    else if (value >= 20 && value < 30)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(MixByValue(Colors.YellowGreen, Colors.Green, value, 20, 29, limit));
    }
    else if (value >= 30 && value < 40)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(MixByValue(Colors.Green, Colors.DarkGreen, value, 30, 39, limit));
    }
    else if (value >= 40 && value < 50)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(MixByValue(Colors.DarkGreen, Colors.Blue, value, 40, 49, limit));
    }
    else if (value >= 50 && value < 60)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(MixByValue(Colors.Blue, Colors.Purple, value, 50, 59, limit));
    }
    else if (value >= 60 && value < 70)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(MixByValue(Colors.Purple, Colors.Red, value, 60, 69, limit));
    }
    else if (value >= 70 && value < 80)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(MixByValue(Colors.Red, Colors.Brown, value, 70, 79, limit));
    }
    else if (value >= 80 && value < 90)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(MixByValue(Colors.Brown, Colors.DarkGray, value, 80, 89, limit));
    }
    else if (value >= 90 && value <= 100)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(MixByValue(Colors.DarkGray, Colors.Black, value, 90, 100, limit));
    }

    return Brushes.Pink;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, por tomarte tu tiempo y responder, tu codigo me ha servido de maravilla muchisimas gracias.